# Knot for Joining the ropes of different thicknesses

Tags: safety, ropes, knots

As, I have been using a Double Fisherman's knot to join the two ropes. With some physics that I know, in Double Fisherman's knot the same amount of pressure (stress) is applied over the two turns of each rope, so making sure there is no significant damage done to any of the rope.

However I believe that if the two ropes are not of equal thickness, or may be say if the difference between the thicknesses is a considerably huge, Double Fisherman's would(?) do some damage to the thinner rope.

In that case how trustworthy are Sheet Bend and Zappelin Bend?

**Edit**:  I am Not going to use this for rappelling at all. I intend to use that as a holding line when me and friends are swimming in a lake nearby. Having said this, We are not entirely relying on this as well.

Comment: What thickness of ropes are you trying to join?  Is this for rappelling?  A "sheet bend" will join 2 ropes, but I've never seen it recommended for rappelling.  If you're trying to join a pair of climbing ropes (i.e., a single rope and a halfrope, or a single rope and a twin rope) there's probably a more specific recommendation

Comment: I assumed op was not referring to Climbing or Rappelling since there were no tags mentioning these. Perhaps WedaPashi could clarify this for us.

Comment: @DavidR: Yes Sir, I am Not going to use this for rappelling at all. I intend to use that as a holding line when me and friends a re swimming in a lake nearby. Having said this, We are not entirely relying on this as well.

Comment: @WedaPashi you're going to use it to tie yourselves together while swimming?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A `Sheet Bend` is designed for joining two lines of different size. If you need additional security use the `Double Sheet Bend`

http://www.animatedknots.com/sheetbend/

Comment: Anyone reading this should note that this knot is absolutely *not* safe for climbing.

Comment: @Felix The question never referenced climbing and includes the statement that 'I am Not going to use this for rappelling'

Answer (score 7):

What is your intended use for those joined ropes? If your life depends on it (you tagged your question with "safety"), I would not recommend using drastically different sized ropes in the first place and I would recommend something that has been well tested by the rock-climbing community. Most rock climbers either join their ropes with the **double fisherman's** (without any damage, as far as I know,) or, when the profile of the knot needs to be small, the **overhand knot** with lots of tail.

I have not heard of the double fisherman's damaging ropes, where did you hear that?

Comment: yeah, I am NOT going to use it for Rappelling at all. I intend to use that as a holding line when me and friends a re swimming in a lake nearby. Having said this, We are not entirely relying on this as well.

Comment: VERY IMPORTANT: The overhand knot must be tied *on a bend*. Because it looks scary (yet is perfectly safe), climbers call this the European Death Knot, or EDK: http://www.animatedknots.com/flatoverhand/index.php

Comment: @Lagerbaer Are you saying overhand on a bend for drastically differently sized lines? I don't see that knot working in the scenario described so clarity helps.

Comment: My scenario is intended for equally sized ropes, which is the scenario where rock climbers use the overhand knot. But again, it has to be the correct version of the overhand (EDK).

Comment: @DudeOnRock: You might want to clarify whether you advocate the double fisherman's or overhand for use in the case of unequal ropes. I assume you're *not* advocating that, and you're just suggesting not to use unequal ropes at all. I think those knots would be unsafe in unequal ropes.

Comment: @BenCrowell: For activities related to rappelling (where the profile of the knot matters) I *do* advocate using the overhand with ropes that are commonly used for climbing. There is an [interesting blog article](http://vikingalpinism.blogspot.com/2012/08/using-overhand-knot-with-ropes-of.html) based on some [test-data](http://user.xmission.com/~tmoyer/testing/EDK.html) the author linked to at the end of the article. I haven't heard of anything going wrong with ropes that have sensible differences in diameter, but if you know of any incidences or testing that show the contrary, please share!

Comment: *I haven't heard of anything going wrong with ropes that have sensible differences in diameter*. What do you consider sensible? I actually can't tell what sizes the OP had in mind (and anyway the OP says this is not life-critical). I was visualizing a factor of two difference in diameter. Were you visualizing something like a 9 mm rope and a 10 mm rope?

Comment: Ah, I see. The Viking Alpinism page describes ropes with a 2:1 diameter ratio. He seems to think it matters exactly how you tie the knot (which rope goes where), and his evidence doesn't seem to be very extensive or taken under controlled conditions. The test data in the second link seemed to be with equal-diameter ropes. It sounds to me like it would definitely be unwise to go around telling people to use the overhand for unequal-diameter ropes without mentioning that there may be a right and wrong way.

Comment: Good point, by "sensible" I mean two ropes rated for climbing (singles, doubles or twins). Look at tests 15 and 17 for 16 data-points with ropes of different diameter. I don't personally believe there is a right way or a wrong way to tie the EDK (after the first inversion the small rope would have to roll over the big rope, and the knot gets tighter with every inversion.) As long it is dressed properly and you have enough tail, I haven't heard of any accidents resulting in its use, but I guess all of this is mute, since the OP didn't ask about rappelling. Should we continue this in chat?

Answer (score 1):

If I was going to rappel on it, and the bulk of the knot wasn't an issue, I would tie a figure-eight in a bight of one piece of rope, then attach the other rope to it using a rewoven figure-eight. This way the knots that had to hold in order to keep me from getting killed would be two almost independent knots, each of which was tied in a single type of rope, and each of which was a standard type of knot (figure-eight) that is widely used in climbing and known to be safe.

As Dopeybob435 has pointed out, this is really a classic application of a sheet bend, but for a life-critical application I would prefer to use something based on a knot that was totally standard for climbing, both so I could be sure of tying it correctly and so that my climbing partner could check my knot.

Comment: Sorry, but this is incorrect and unsafe. The double fisherman's or flat overhand are much better knots that do not have ropes rubbing on each other.

Comment: @Felix: I think you're incorrect, and in fact your suggestion would be the unsafe one. The knots you're suggesting are not intended for ropes of very unequal thickness and there's no reason to think they'd be secure in such a situation. Rubbing would only be an issue if one rope was to travel through a loop in another rope while under load. That's not the case here, where the two loops are like the links of a chain.

Comment: As discussed in the comments under DudeOnRock's answer, we may not be visualizing the same ratio of diameters. My answer is describing what I'd do if the ropes' diameters differed by a factor of 2, and in that situation I stand by my statement that your recommendations would be extremely dangerous.

Comment: You could adapt that approach to tie one figure 8 loop, then tie the other through and round it so as to look like a reef knot in the middle. Or tie them independently, then attach the two by passing a working end through the eye of the other rope then through the eye of the same rope. Same sort of thing as you would do to attach two slings, or rubber bands.